# pandas for loop for dataframe to csv - column question

Tags: python, pandas, selenium, for-loop

I have a for loop created to iterate over a dataframe and export it out to csv

```
for x in range (len(price)):
    df = pd.DataFrame(data1, columns= ['Price', 'Location', 'Area size'])
    data1 = {'Price': [price[x].text],
        'Location': [location[x].text],
        'Size': [area_size[x].text]}
    df.to_csv('static/home.csv', header="False", mode="a")
driver.quit()
```

the csv is created successfully but as the "df" is in the for loop the columns Price/Location/Areasize is also created as many times the foor loop goes and it look like this

I tried removing the df outside of the foor loop like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data1, columns= ['Price', 'Location', 'Area size'])
for x in range (len(price)):
    data1 = {'Price': [price[x].text],
        'Location': [location[x].text],
        'Size': [area_size[x].text]}
    df.to_csv('static/home.csv', header="False", mode="a")
driver.quit()
```

but then it gives an error that "data1 is not defined". Any idea how could I create the for loop by not iterating over the Price/Location/Area columns so they are not created multiple times?

Comment: Can you share a sample of your dataframe.

Comment: You don't want to **create the columns as many time as the loop** is running, but you use to_csv with the mode append in the loop too. I'm not sure I understand the interest of this? is i it because for example `[price[x].text]` or the  other one are too big?

Comment: if I put df = pd.DataFrame(data1, columns= ['Price', 'Location', 'Area size']) in the foorloop then I will get "Price, Location, Area" words exported into my csv file as many times as the loop goes. I dont want those to be displayed in the csv only the actual values of the Price, Location, Area size

Comment: @user3916 I got your problem it is because you need to use `header=False` and not `header="False"` as you do, note that False is not between `"` to make it work. so with the first loop, replace in `to_csv` with `header=False`, it should do what you are looking for

Comment: Yep it works now almost :-) Now,  I get my values finally from Price etc but I still need the first row to be the actual name of the columns then for the rest just populate the values... Any idea how to do that with this for loop?

Comment: @user3916 try `df.to_csv('static/home.csv', header=True if x==0 else False, mode="a")`

Comment: Thanks will try this. I made it work like this but its a bit ugly...

`df = pd.DataFrame(columns= ['Price', 'Location', 'Area size'])
df.to_csv('static/home.csv', header=True)
for x in range (len(price)):
    data1 = {'Price': [price[x].text],
        'Location': [location[x].text],
        'Size': [area_size[x].text]}
    df = pd.DataFrame(data1, columns= ['Price', 'Location', 'Area size'])
    df.to_csv('static/home.csv', header=False, mode="a")
driver.quit()`

basically created a df outside and inside of the loop

Comment: yours works too didnt know that you can use if/else there, thank!

Answer (score 0):

You should use `df.append()`

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data1, columns= ['Price', 'Location', 'Area size'])
for x in range (len(price)):
    # data1 is dataframe , i dont #know how your data looks like, so #you need to prepare it on your own #before append

    df=df.append(data1)
 df.to_csv(“path”)
```

Comment: Thanks tried this but I get the following error:
NameError: name 'data1' is not defined

If I leave the "df =" inside of the loop then I get the column names wrote to the csv as many times as price. I just want to have the values of Price, Location, Area Size wrote to the csv or appended but the columns names Price, Location, Area size exported once